# Google Cloud direct default port to GlassFish port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, glassfish

A GlassFish application hosted in a Google Cloud VM Instance is running in port 8080. I need to direct traffic of default port 80 to port 8080. What is the best way to achieve that?

I tried to set port 80 as GlassFish port, but failed as on Ubuntu we can't listen on a port lower than 1024.

Comment: Can't you edit the domain.xml and change the listening port to 80?  See ... http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/java/changeglassfishport_4.1.aspx.   If this doesn't work, please describe the error reported.

Comment: On Unix system we can't listen on a port lower than 1024 as a non-root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Linux feature `iptables` to redirect traffic received on one port to a different port.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

Double-check the documentation as you do not mention the version of Linux that you are running.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Comment: It gives the following error. -bash: /etc/init.d/iptables: No such file or directory

Comment: I installed sudo apt-get install iptables-persistent and it works perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance group for your VM. Create a Load Balancer with that directs external port 80 traffic to port 8080 on your VM.

Comment: Thank you. I could have done it, but the accepted answer resolved the issue. So I did not attempt your solution. But this will be definitely helpful in future.

Comment: Glad to hear, good luck. In general, `iptables` is a very brittle, un-scalable fix. Networking should be handled by the network.

Comment: Travis, be careful with blind comments. Kubernetes networking uses iptables to control the network connections between pods (and between nodes), handling many of the networking and port forwarding rules.

Comment: Of course, plenty of network components in GCP and elsewhere make use of managed `iptables` under the hood. Here, we're talking about a web server running on a VM instance wherein I'd not recommend manually configuring iptables. Web servers should serve web content, networks should route packets. Let's help OP architect his system in a way that is consistent with best practices in the cloud, since that's where he's running his workload.

Comment: Travis, let's go offline. My email is in the Google system.